# How to add a ng-admin table to a sub element of a page?

Tags: ng-admin

I want to add ng-admin tables to some dom element, such as a div in tabs, or a modal window, is there any way to change the ng-admin table to bind to other ui-view?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the [most requested features](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/issues/446) for ng-admin, and it's currently not possible. A patch is in the works to make it possible (https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/pull/759), but it's a BC break. It will probably be merged for ng-admin 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link, check whether this is useful :

https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin

First you have to Grab ng-admin from your favorite package manager, npm or bower,then Add the ng-admin.min.css and ng-admin.min.js to the HTML, add a , and configure the admin